# Callback from WhatsApp after sharing is finished in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I'm integrating WhatsApp in my App. Followed 'https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/23559013', picked 'Custom URL Scheme' approach and succeeded.

I have one query, Is it possible to get a callback after sharing is done? in any approach: 'Custom URL Scheme' or 'Share Extension' or 'Document Interaction'.

---

I found this somewhere(http://socialize.github.io/socialize-sdk-ios/whatsapp.html):

> Since WhatsApp uses URL Schemes to navigate from your app, there is no
>   callback mechanism to return to your app from WhatsApp once the user
>   has sent the share as a WhatsApp message. Users will be notified of
>   this via a UIAlertView before navigating to WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried that before but based on your information App Extension looks like a workaround. Just checked the [App Extension documentation for Share](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html) and found that we have a [completion handler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1411301-completerequest) once share is completed.

A part from completion handler document:

> Tells the host app to complete the app extension request with an array
>   of result items.

So you will be getting some information inside user info key under `returningItems` parameter.